# th:attr in Thymeleaf XML mode lowercases attribute name

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

What are the differences between XML and HTML mode when doing variable insertion?  I can't find anything in the docs and couldn't find the answer after half-an-hour of looking at the source code.

See the issue I created for this for an explanation of what I want to do and the behavior https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/896

```
<EntityDescriptor
...
    th:attr="entityID=${entityId},validUntil=${validUntil}">
... 
</EntityDescriptor>
```

The resulting output is

```
<EntityDescriptor
...
    entityID="what_the_entity_id_is" validuntil="correct_timestamp">
... 
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Note that valid**U**ntil becomes valid**u**ntil.  I've never seen this behavior before.

**Does XML mode not support th:attr?**. If so where can I find this to lower case in the source code or docs?

Answer (score 0):

This represents a *partial* answer.

## Why is the xml lowercased?

The real answer to this is: **it isn't**.  When viewed from a web browser DOM this is the case, but a curl request on the endpoint exposing this xml file confirmed that the attribute names are properly cased.

## What are the differences between XML and HTML mode?

This remains **unanswered** as I am noticing some differences in behavior.  For example I'm unable to insert *th:block* elements in arbitrary places in the XML code.  I believe this may have to do with the XML being more strictly parsed than HTML, but an answer to this part of the question would be very helpful.